# Deleting a file in amazon s3 from rails inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am working on rails app using mongoid and paperclip.This is one of the model:

```
class Document
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :time, type: Time
  field :radius, type: Float
  has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar
end
```

Now this model is getting deleted after some time (according to time field), so the image url everything get deleted. Now I also want to delete the image from s3bucket also. for reference my path on s3 is "`:avatar/:id/:style.:extension"`

Any guesses how to proceed?

Comment: http://amazon.rubyforge.org/
It should help.

Comment: thanks was reading this only, I think I have found the solution.

Comment: cheers (9 more letters required to comment)